curl request to hit fastapi based Post API
I have created a fastAPI based endpoint which is responsible for accepting month, card_no, schema_order as a payload parameter and perform db select query and creates a csv file.
code snippet:
# Endpoint to generate CSV file
@app.post("/download-csv/")
def download_csv(month: str, card_no: list[int] = Query(...), schema_order: list[str] = Query(None), page_no: int = Query(None)):
    logger.info("Info: Inside Download CSV controller")
    return download_csv_data(month, card_no, schema_order, page_no, logger)

Now I am trying to perform post curl request to the above api which is giving me 422 Unprocessable Entity
curl request:
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://127.0.0.1:8000/download-csv/' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "month": "2024-01-06",
    "card_no": [123456789],
    "schema_order": ["id", "card_type", "score", "card_no", "month"],
    "page_no": 2
  }'

Error which I am getting after this curl request is :
"POST /download-csv/ HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity

{"detail":[{"type":"missing","loc":["query","month"],"msg":"Field required","input":null},{"type":"list_type","loc":["query","card_no"],"msg":"Input should be a valid list","input":null}]}

I need help to perform curl request to this API.

You've define the parameters as query parameters, (i.e. ?month=...&card_no=...&...), but are giving them as JSON body parameters (Body()). You'll have to define them correctly or submit them correctly instead of mingling them.
